# Get the same table data in separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, subquery

I have an SQL table in this format

```
ColumnID    Column1     Column2     Column3
-------------------------------------------
230         ABC         20          1
230         DEF         14.50       1
230         XYZ         10          1
230         DEF         09          0
230         ABC         30          0
230         MNO         16          0
230         OOP         07          1
```

I want the output to be the following for ColumnID based on Column3 = 1 and Column3 = 0

```
output_Column1      output_Column2      output_Column3      output_Column4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC                 20                  ABC                 30
DEF                 14.50               DEF                 09
OOP                 07                  MNO                 16
XYZ                 10                  NULL                 NULL
```

Using self join I got 6 records which is incorrect. It's not mandatory to have Column1 value with column3 = 1 matching with column1 value with column3 =0.

Please help!

Comment: So there is always one record per string in Column1 and Column3 = 1? And zero or one records per string in Column1 and Column3 = 0? And ColumnID has no meaning here?

Comment: Thorsten,
Its not mandatory to have a record for column3=1 or column3=0. If exists, I would like to have the result in the mentioned format. 

@all,
I will try out your solutions and let you know.

Comment: Why do you join OOP with MNO? How are they related? Why these two and not, say, XYZ with MNO?

Comment: There is no relation for OOP with MNO here. The requirement is that for a columnID, make two sets one with column3=1 and the other column3=0. There can be only one record for column1 with column3=1 and  column3=0 i.e., ABC will not have one more record either with column3=0 or column3=1.

Also, I am looking for a direct query. It may not be just a join :)

Comment: So I could just as well combine XYZ with MNO and leave OOP without a partner, yes? And what is a "direct query"? Are you saying you want to access your table just once instead of performing a self-join? Why would you add such restriction?

Comment: output_Column1, output_Column2 should show data with column3=1 and output_Column3, output_Column4 should show data with column3=0.

What I mean by direct query is no other DB objects such as UDF need to be created in order to achieve this. A straight query is what I am looking for. :)

Comment: Again: You couple ABC and ABC because they are equal. Same for DEF. I cannot couple ABC with MNO, because ABC *has* a sibling. Right?  That leaves you with MNO for column3 = 0 and with OOP and XYZ with column3 = 1. So I can either couple OOP with MNO and leave XYZ alone or couple XYZ with MNO and leave OOP alone. Correct?

Comment: yes as long as they fall into the column3 sets correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Column3 = 1 THEN Column1 ELSE NULL END) output_Column1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Column3 = 1 THEN Column2 ELSE NULL END) output_Column2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Column3 = 0 THEN Column1 ELSE NULL END) output_Column3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Column3 = 0 THEN Column2 ELSE NULL END) output_Column4
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ColumnID, Column1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment Saharsh!
The solution is close enough. But I don't want NULL to appear if there's no match

output_Column1 output_Column2 output_Column3 output_Column4
NULL NULL 58 12.0000
NULL NULL 105 10.0000
213 20.0000 NULL NULL
1042 0.2300 1042 50.0000

I am looking for,

output_Column1 output_Column2 output_Column3 output_Column4
213         20.0000         58         12.0000
1042         0.2300         105         10.0000
NULL         NULL         1042            50.0000

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT t1.Column1 AS output_Column1,t1.Column2 
    AS output_Column2, t2.Column1 AS     
            output_Column3,t2.Column2 AS output_Column4 FROM mytable 
            as t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable 
      as t2 ON t1.COLUMNID=t2.COLUMNID WHERE t1.COlumn3 =0 AND t1.Column3=3
```

or Alternatively

```
   SELECT t1.Column1 AS output_Column1,t1.Column2 
        AS output_Column2, t2.Column1 AS     
                output_Column3,t2.Column2 AS output_Column4 FROM mytable 
                as t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable 
          as t2 ON t1.COLUMNID=t2.COLUMNID WHERE EXISTS
     (
       SELECT ColumnID FROM mytable WHERE COLUMNID=t1.COlumnID and Column3=0 AND COlumn3=3
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from your comment I gather that there are Column1 values for which

- only one record with Column3 = 0 exists and no record with Column3 = 1
- only one record with Column3 = 1 exists and no record with Column3 = 0
- one record with Column3 = 1 exists and one record with Column3 = 0

And

- There never exist more than one record with Column3 = 0 for a Column1 value.
- There never exist more than one record with Column3 = 1 for a Column1 value.

Self-join the table, one time for column3 = 0, one time for column3 = 1. Use a full outer join, in order to get records that have no entry for column3 = 0 or 1.

```
select
  m1.column1 as output_column1,
  m1.column2 as output_column2,
  m0.column1 as output_column3,
  m0.column2 as output_column4
from (select * from mytable where column3 = 0) m0
full outer join (select * mytable where column3 = 1) m1
on m0.column1 = m1.column1;
```

You can achieve the same without a self-join:

```
select
  max(case when column3 = 1 then column1 end) as output_column1,
  max(case when column3 = 1 then column2 end) as output_column2,
  max(case when column3 = 0 then column1 end) as output_column3,
  max(case when column3 = 0 then column2 end) as output_column4
from mytable
where column3 in (0,1)
group by column1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Thorsten.
I am getting the same output I was getting with Saharsh solution. I modified the question for better understanding. Please suggest me if any.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see what the OOP record has to do with the MNO record.

Comment: There is no relation for OOP with MNO here. The requirement is that for a columnID, make two sets one with column3=1 and the other column3=0. There can be only one record for column1 with column3=1 and column3=0 i.e., ABC will not have one more record either with column3=0 or column3=1. Also, I am looking for a direct query. It may not be just a join :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a separate answer for your changes to your request make it a different question.

SQL queries select related data from a relational database. In your case however you select non-related data. It doesn't matter if you couple OOP with MNO and leave XYZ alone or couple XYZ with MNO and leave OOP alone. You join records although they have nothing to do with each other. (Neither OOP nor XYZ have something to do with MNO.)

Usually you would select

```
output_Column1      output_Column2      output_Column3      output_Column4
ABC                 20                  ABC                 30
DEF                 14.50               DEF                 09
                                        MNO                 16
OOP                 07                                          
XYZ                 10
```

But you want it to be

```
output_Column1      output_Column2      output_Column3      output_Column4
ABC                 20                  ABC                 30
DEF                 14.50               DEF                 09
OOP                 07                  MNO                 16
XYZ                 10
```

so as to save rows. You would normally do this in your app in which you display the data, i.e. use Java, C#, PHP or whatever to fill the display grid.

If you want to achieve the same in SQL by joining unrelated records, you must create a relation. For instance add row numbers to all column3=0 records that have no sibling with column3=1 and add row numbers to all column3=1 records that have no sibling with column3=0. Then couple the first with the second by row number.

```
select
  m1.column1 as output_column1,
  m1.column2 as output_column2,
  m0.column1 as output_column3,
  m0.column2 as output_column4
from (select * from mytable where column3 = 0) m0
join (select * mytable where column3 = 1) m1 on m1.column1 = m0.column1
union all
select
  m1.column1 as output_column1,
  m1.column2 as output_column2,
  m0.column1 as output_column3,
  m0.column2 as output_column4
from 
(
  select
    row_number() over (order by column1) as joinkey,
    column1,
    column2
  from mytable 
  where column3 = 0
  and not exists
  (
    select *
    from mytable couple
    where couple.column1 = mytable.column1
    and couple.column3 = 1
  )
) m0
full outer join 
(
  select
    row_number() over (order by column1) as joinkey,
    column1,
    column2
  from mytable 
  where column3 = 1
  and not exists
  (
    select *
    from mytable couple
    where couple.column1 = mytable.column1
    and couple.column3 = 0
  )
) m1 on m1.joinkey = m0.joinkey;
```

Comment: Thorsten, Thank you for the effort. After implementing the above query, it leads to incorrect resultset – 

`ID output_column1 output_column2 output_column3 output_column4
157 213 20.0000 618 77.0000
157 1042 0.2300 1042 34.2600
157 213 20.0000 213 58.3250
157 105 60.0000 105 10.3250
157 92 18.0000 92 55.2300
157 58 20.0000 58 12.0000
157 105 60.0000 105 10.0000
157 1042 0.2300 1042 10.0000
157 213 20.0000 213 80.0000
157 1042 0.2300 1042 90.0000
157 92 18.0000 92 25.0000
157 1042 0.2300 1042 50.0000`

Comment: Your data doesn't tell me anything. I don't even see where a row ends. And I don't know what your data is. So in plain English: What is wrong about the results you are getting? Are you getting too many records, too few, duplicate records? Please stay within your example. What would be different with my query from the desired result you told us?